# "Column count does not match" for h2 database Select query using projection in Spring-Boot @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a Spring-Boot app that has some native queries that use content projection. It runs Postgres in production and works fine. I'm trying to set up integration tests for the repositories using `@DataJpaTest` and a h2 in-memory database, but my queries that are using content projection are failing with a JdbcSQLException out of the driver:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match

I successfully save to the TestEntityManager, so there are records in the database, but I am unable to invoke the SELECT via the repository method. **It works properly in production on Postgres -- is this a limitation to h2 and is there a workaround I could apply so I can properly test this?**

The repository method looks like this (one inner join, two params in the where clause, table names and columns changed to protect the guilty):

```
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "SELECT order.id, order.total, pizza.name " +
                   "FROM example.order " +
                   "INNER JOIN example.pizza USING (pizza_id) " +
                   "WHERE order.customer_id = :custId " +
                   "AND order.order_date = :orderDate ",
           countQuery = "SELECT count(order.id) " +
                        "FROM example.order " +
                        "INNER JOIN example.pizza USING (pizza_id) " +
                        "WHERE order.customer_id = :custId " +
                        "AND order.order_date = :orderDate")
    <T> Page<T> findAllByCustIdAndOrderDate(String custId, OffsetDateTime orderDate, Pageable paging, Class<T> type);
}
```

And the projection looks like this:

```
public interface PizzaOrderProjection {
  Long getId();
  Double getTotal();
  String getName();
}
```

The exception triggers when I call `findAllByCustIdAndOrderDate`, and the SQL statement that it prints is causing it is the SELECT. The SELECT it prints looks perfectly normal:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ SELECT
        order.id,
        order.total,
        pizza.name 
    FROM
        example.order 
    INNER JOIN
        example.pizza USING (pizza_id) 
    WHERE
        order.customer_id = ? 
        AND order.order_date = ?  limit ?
2019-04-09 12:42:18.704  WARN 17568 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 21002, SQLState: 21S02
2019-04-09 12:42:18.708 ERROR 17568 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column count does not match; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the error message actually has **nothing** to do with the underlying issue.

The H2 database does not support the `using` keyword on the `inner join` clause, only the `on` keyword.

The issue was resolved by changing the inner join to use `on` instead, like this:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "SELECT order.id, order.total, pizza.name " +
                   "FROM example.order " +
                   "INNER JOIN example.pizza ON order.pizza_id = pizza.pizza_id " +
                   "WHERE order.customer_id = :custId " +
                   "AND order.order_date = :orderDate ",
           countQuery = "SELECT count(order.id) " +
                        "FROM example.order " +
                        "INNER JOIN example.pizza ON order.pizza_id = pizza.pizza_id " +
                        "WHERE order.customer_id = :custId " +
                        "AND order.order_date = :orderDate")
    <T> Page<T> findAllByCustIdAndOrderDate(String custId, OffsetDateTime orderDate, Pageable paging, Class<T> type);
}
```

This change makes the queries valid in both postgres and h2.

Comment: Had a same issue with SQL Server keyword `(nolock)`. Query was: `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT count(d.id) FROM doc_log d (NOLOCK) "
      + "WHERE d.doc_value = ?1 AND d.status in (?2)")
  int countByDocValueAndStatusIn(String docValue, List<Long> statuses);`
When removed `(nolock)` everything worked.